# Piechart Labels are not visible on image

Tags: iphone, ios, core-plot

I have created the Piechart(CPTGraphHostingView) using corePlot_0.4 library . Piechart displayed properly on UIView with labelforPiechart on it  , 
        Also from that piechart view I have created the image to send it through email. But while I got the image from piechart view using GraphicsContext only the piechart is displayed on the image the labels are not visible.

Below is my code for get the image from piechart view:

```
// Get the image from piechartview

-(UIImage *) GetImageFromView{
    if (NULL != UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions)
                UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions PieChartView.bounds.size, NO, 0);
            else
                UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(PieChartView.view.bounds.size);

            CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
            CGContextSaveGState(context);               
            [rpsvc.view.layer renderInContext:context];
            CGContextRestoreGState(context);

            UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();      
    return image;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It appears that if there is no background set for the graph the labels can't be seen by some image viewers.

Try this;

```
 CPTColor *background_colour = [CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1];
 graph.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:background_colour];
```

It just sets the background colour of the graph to black and sets the alpha.